# Cannot read property 'length' of null with ramda's R.cond

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

Here's is 2 approaches the uncommented one works and the second one with ramdajs doesn't work:

```
    // const dies = col && 2 > count > 3
    // const lives =
    //  (col && (count === 2 || count === 3)) || (!col && count === 3)

    // return dies ? null : lives ? true : null

    const result = (_col, _count) =>
        R.cond([
            [_col && (_count === 2 || _count === 3), true],
            [!_col && _count === 3, true],
            [_col && 2 > _count > 3, null],
            [R.T, null]
        ])

    return result(col, count)
```

I get an error `Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Comment: [`cond`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond) accepts functions, not expressions.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to rewrite this with ramda?

Comment: Most directly, you could replace `[_col && (_count === 2 || _count === 3), true]` with `[(_col, _count) => _col && (_count === 2 || _count === 3), always(true)]`, etc.  But there's probably a better way.

Comment: You cannot do `a > b >  c` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to write the [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) rules too directly.

I think something like this would do fine:

```
const nextGeneration = (col, count) => count == 3 || (col && count == 2)
```

This returns a boolean rather than your `true`|`null`.  That strikes me as cleaner, but if you want the null, just add a `|| null` to the end.

This does not use Ramda.  I see no reason to do so here (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author.)  But if you wanted, I'm sure we could turn this into some Ramda points-free version, but it would likely be much less readable.

BTW, there seems to be something wrong with any of your versions.  What is `2 > count > 3` supposed to mean?  Even if that did expand into `2 > count && count > 3` in JS, which it doesn't, this would never be true, since 2 < 3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got a way with this:    `const optimalPopulation = col && (count === 2 || count === 3)`
`const reproduction = !col && count === 3`
`const lives = optimalPopulation || reproduction`
`return lives ? lives : null` :)

Comment: @JaredSmith: thanks for fixing the typo.  Usually I proofread better.